# Can I add rigging bones to a model imported from Blender inside Unity?

Tags: unity, blender, rigging

I created a model in Blender but recently I stumbled upon a video claiming that you can add rigging to a model in Unity. So instead of rigging in Blender, is it possible to do it in Unity?

Comment: If you have seen a video that does this, does that not answer your question with a "Yes, it is possible"?

Comment: Linking the video you're talking about would help here, so we can see the context.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Htl7ysv10Qs&t=331s

Answer (score 2):

3D packages provide a number of ways to create joints for your humanoid rig. You must  use an external 3d modelling software to manually rig and add weights, you cannot do it in Unity.

But before we explore what's with the new animation rigging let's see how animation layers work in unity. Unity uses Animation Layers for managing complex state machines for different body parts. An example of this is if you have a lower-body layer for walking-jumping, and an upper-body layer for throwing objects / shooting. It's an easy way to override and map different animations at once. But this has its own constraints. What if you want to add an animation where you want your character to pick up something while walking you need an animation for walking and picking up and then add a interactables layer and override the top part of the body to use the pick up animation. This requires you to make many animations.

Using layers require pre-made animations and it enables overriding certain parts of the rig. This is a great feature, but what if we could override certain parts of rig to work procedurally? That would lead to amazing possibilities. Unity made a clever decision by combining procedural animation with layer rig overriding. Complete procedural animation doesn't look that good but combining it with pre-made animation, we can create some amazing stuff. Imagine being able to control certain parts of the rig using code and remaining using the pre-made animations.

The Animation Rigging package for Unity enables to set up procedural motion on animated skeletons at runtime. You can use a set of predefined animation constraints to manually build a control rig hierarchy for a character or develop your own custom constraints in C#. This makes it possible to do powerful things during gameplay such as world interactions, skeletal deformation rigging, and physics-based secondary motion.